# two lines in newcommand

Tags: macros, line-breaking, forest

I am working on a flowchart with the forest package. As I am using the same structur over and over again, I would like to define a new command. However I have some issues in getting a linebreak within the newcommand and some arguments don't do what they are supposed to do.

My tree (small version) looks like this:

[image: Tree how it is supposed to look]

and are created with this line of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    
    [\huge \textbf{Main}, circle, draw
        [\large{Print\_logo()\\\scriptsize(use output)},align=center, draw]
        
        [\large{InitialiseParameters() \\ \scriptsize(use initialise)},align=center, draw]
        
        [\large{check\_parameters() \\ \scriptsize(use parameters)},align=center, draw]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

I want to have a command like

```
\newcommand{\subtree}[2]{{\large{#1} \\ \scriptsize{use #2}}, align=center, draw}
```

What I get, when I use ***\subtree{Test}{module}*** is:

[image: output of newcommand] (please ignore the weird lines - they come from the lines in the tree)

So basically I have two problems:

1. the \\ doesn't work
2. the align=center and draw are recognized as text, instead of aligning and drawing a box.

I tried breaking it up in two commands, which worked even less, I tried using \newline and \linebreak instead of the \\. Nothing seems to work. I looked through the forum and googled a lot, but didn't find a solution. I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers!

---

Edit:
If I do

```
\newcommand{\twolines}[2]{{\large{#1} \\ \scriptsize{use #2}}}
```

and then use

```
\begin{forest}
  [\twolines{Test}{module},align=center,draw]
\end{forest}
```

I get what I want:
[image]

However when I try to go further with my attempt like this:

```
\newcommand{\subtree}[2]{\twolines{#1}{#2}, align=center, draw}
```

I have the same problem as before.

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: What do you mean with MWE? The miniexample is there, with the \begin{forest}...\end{forest}. You need to use the \usepackage{forest}

Comment: Exactly, I need to add `\usepackage`, and `\documentclass`, and whatnot. A Minimal Working Example is something starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduces the issue, such that we can copy/paste the code.

Comment: Ah okay, I edited my example. It should work now.

Comment: Aside: `\large` and `\scriptsize` don't take arguments.  They change the font to that size until the current group ends.  Since you're changing the font size again or ending the current group before you type anything, you don't see anything off, but if you have `\large{#1}#2`, then everything will be large.

Comment: Ah right, I completely forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand\tln[2]{\large #1\\      % tln: two line node
                   \scriptsize #2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes (common style)
    draw, 
    align=center,
ROOT/.style = {circle, font=\huge\bfseries},
% tree
    edge = {-},
    s sep=2mm,
    l sep=4mm
            }
[Main, ROOT,
    [\tln{Print\_logo()}{(use output)}] 
    [\tln{InitialiseParameters()}{(use initialise)}]
    [\tln{check\_parameters()}{(use parameters)}]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is, I will also have subsubtrees, which will have other shapes and sizes. So I want to specify the size and shape of the "node" within my command.

Comment: @Karfloffel, that is bad idea. Better is than define a number of styles for different shapes as I do for root node. This will be, at least to m<y opinion, simpler from what you try to have. Now arise a question, if the forest is the right tool for what you like to have. At least, please edit your question and add  to it more information, what is your final goal. The best would be by some sketch, which show desired tree.

Comment: Why is this a bad idea? Your solution with defining different styles also works, thanks!

Comment: @Karfloffel, because your focusing in defining new command and not use features of `forest` is abusing it. For example, accepted solution repeat nodes formatting at each modes, meanwhile in my solution this is done globally for all nodes. Since you not provide asked additional information, I cant help you further. BTW, my solution is designed in spirit of `forest` :-)

Comment: Ah my bad, I don't know enough about this. In this case I will accept your answere, thanks for the additional explaination :) The reason why i didn't provide additional info was, because I figured out how to adapt your solution to the thing I need.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand{\subtree}[2]{\large #1\\\scriptsize use #2, align=center, draw}
\bracketset{action character=@}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [\huge\bfseries Main, circle, draw, 
        [@\subtree{Print\_logo()}{output}]
        [@\subtree{InitialiseParameters()}{initialise}]
        [@\subtree{check\_parameters()}{parameters}]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the "for children" part defines, that all following branches have this layout, right? I want to be able to have subsubtrees as well, so this doesn't fully do the job, which is why I want to specify the layout of the nodes within the command.

Comment: Okay, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: perfect thank you! This is what I wanted :D

Comment: In my first answer, you didn’t consider the global setting to be good. That's why I fixed it. Then you accept a global solution. I really don't understand your purpose anymore.